# SQL Help : Exception report - extended

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Extend on: [SQL help - exception report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61807952/sql-help-exception-report)

In my previous post I requested hep for:

I have:

- a company table (CompanyID, CompanyName),
- Date table (Datekey int, date, isTradingHoliday 0/1),
- Fact table (id, datekey, companyID, StockClosePrice)

I need help to write a query to find for which days and for which companies I don't have data in the fact table.

SQL below does the job

```
select c.*, d.*
from companies c
cross join dates d 
where d.isTradingHoliday = 0
  and not exists (select 1 from facts f 
                  where f.datekey = d.datekey and f.companyID = c.companyID)
```

I have noticed for some companies, for some days, `StockClosePrice` is 0.00 - I want to include those in the exception report.

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just want one more condition in the subquery:

```
where d.isTradingHoliday = 0 and
      not exists (select 1
                  from facts f
                  where f.datekey = d.datekey and
                        f.companyID = c.companyID and
                        f.StockClosePrice <> 0.00
                 )
```

Comment: Great...is there a way I can flag the rows which are for 0.00 and which are for not existing --- or get the value as 0.00 or Null in select clause?

Comment: @ITNube . . . That is a rather different question, but you can use an `exists` subquery in the `select` (in a `case` expression) to distinguish different cases.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @Year   int = 2019

SELECT  CT.*, DT.*
FROM            FactTable       FT
    RIGHT JOIN   CompanyTable    CT  ON  CT.CompanyID    =   FT.companyID
    RIGHT JOIN   DateTable       DT  ON  DT.Datekey      =   FT.datekey

WHERE
        YEAR(DT.DateField)  =   @Year
    AND FT.ID               IS  NULL
```

Comment: Since you want all of those Dates and Companies missing in your Fact Table, the StockCloseprice is irrelevant.