# SQL Help : Exception report - extended 2

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Extending on [SQL Help : Exception report - extended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61821248/sql-help-exception-report-extended)

In my previous posts I requested help for:

I have:

- a company table (CompanyID, CompanyName)
- Date table (Datekey int, date, isTradingHoliday 0/1)
- Fact table (id, datekey, companyID, StockClosePrice)

I needed help to write a query to find for which days and for which companies I don't have data in the fact table or there is data but value is 0.00

```
select c.*, d.*
from companies c
cross join dates d 
where d.isTradingHoliday = 0 and
      not exists (select 1
                  from facts f
                  where f.datekey = d.datekey and
                        f.companyID = c.companyID and
                        f.StockClosePrice <> 0.00
                 )
```

Now extending to the previous request I need to flag the rows which are for 0.00 and which are for not existing in fact table. Basically I need to somehow separate them and show them in a report.

I would appreciate any help with this.

Comment: Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question. Although it may be helpful to reference a prior question, this one should stand on its own. With DDL. And sample data. And expected results.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  
        CT.*
    ,   DT.*
    ,   Flag    =   CASE                                                    --  !!! DO NOT CHANGE THE ORDER OF THE CASES !!!
                        WHEN    FT.ID               IS  NULL    THEN    1   --  No record on Fact Table
                        WHEN    FT.StockClosePrice  =   0       THEN    2   --  Exists in Fact Table, but with StockClosePrice = 0
                                                                ELSE    0   --  Exists in Fact Table, and has  StockClosePrice > 0
                    END  
FROM            FactTable       FT
    RIGHT JOIN  CompanyTable    CT  ON  CT.CompanyID    =   FT.companyID
    RIGHT JOIN  DateTable       DT  ON  DT.Datekey      =   FT.datekey
```